# Fetch only latest revision record from table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that holds item's revision information. I want to get only latest revision of the item. The data is stored in table something like this.

```
Item_Number   Revision       Latest_flag
Item-01       Introductory   NULL
Item-02       Introductory   NULL
Item-02       1              NULL
Item-02       2              1
Item-03       Introductory   NULL
Item-03       1              1
```

In case the revision is only `Introductory` Latest revision flag is NULL, but if the revision is changed, the latest flag will become 1.

The result I want would be something like this

```
Item_Number   Revision       Latest_flag
Item-01       Introductory   NULL
Item-02       2              1
Item-03       1              1
```

If I apply only this check it `WHERE Latest_flag = 1` it omits the `Introductory` rows which only have initial revision as in that case it is not saving flag for latest revision.

Comment: The Introductory rows never having a `Latest=1` is a bug; fix the bug.  The whole concept of having such a flag is so that you Don't need to use row numbers or other tricks to find the latest value.

Comment: @MatBailie I don't think Oracle Agile team is going to take my advice seriously :)

Comment: Oracle have mechanisms for raising bugs on their products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rank rows, and then select ones with desired rank:

```
SQL> with test (item_number, revision, latest_flag) as
  2    (select 'item-01', 'introductory', null from dual union all
  3     select 'item-02', 'introductory', null from dual union all
  4     select 'item-02', '1'           , null from dual union all
  5     select 'item-02', '2'           , 1    from dual union all
  6     select 'item-03', 'introductory', null from dual union all
  7     select 'item-03', '1'           , 1    from dual
  8    ),
  9  temp as
 10    -- rank rows
 11    (select item_number, revision, latest_flag,
 12            rank() over (partition by item_number order by latest_flag) rnk
 13     from test
 14    )
 15  select item_number, revision, latest_flag
 16  from temp
 17  where rnk = 1
 18  order by item_number;

ITEM_NU REVISION     LATEST_FLAG
------- ------------ -----------
item-01 introductory
item-02 2                      1
item-03 1                      1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select item_number,
       coalesce(max(case when latest = 1 then revision end),
                max(revision)
               ) as revisition,
       max(latest) as latest
from t
group by item_number;
```